# Elegant way to namespace templates in Django

Tags: python, django, templates, namespaces

Django tutorial suggests to organize templates like this:

> Within the templates directory you have just created, create another directory called polls, and within that create a file called index.html. In other words, your template should be at polls/templates/polls/index.html. Because of how the app_directories template loader works as described above, you can refer to this template within Django simply as polls/index.html.

Tutorial also tells what happens if I just put index.html in polls/templates:

> Now we might be able to get away with putting our templates directly in polls/templates (rather than creating another polls subdirectory), but it would actually be a bad idea. Django will choose the first template it finds whose name matches, and if you had a template with the same name in a different application, Django would be unable to distinguish between them. We need to be able to point Django at the right one, and the easiest way to ensure this is by namespacing them. That is, by putting those templates inside another directory named for the application itself.

My assumption was that as long as I'm creating an isolated application, it's templates are also isolated from other apps without any subfolder magic.

Is there another way to namespace, so I can refer to template as index.html without creating duplicated folders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way templates are organised in a Django project is very flexible.  So there's nothing to stop you ordering the template files however you want, as long as you specify the correct template name in the view.  For example, you could use a Class Based View for the list of Polls, specifying the `template_name` as whatever you like:

```
# polls/views.py
from django.views.generic import ListView
from .models import Poll

class PollList(ListView):
    model = Poll
    template_name = 'any/path/you/choose/any_name.html'
```

Having said that, it's good to create a consistent template structure to keep the code maintainable.  I'd recommend at the very least keeping your page-level templates (things which are used to return the whole html page) structured in folders with their relevant app name, and anything you include (snippets included with the `{% include %}` tag) within `includes` subfolders, like so:

```
templates
   - base.html
   polls
       - poll_list.html
       includes
           - poll_votes.html
```

**Edit:**

If you still need namespaces despite this, you could use [URL namespaces](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces).

Comment: I can see this. However, I'm still a bit concerned by the fact that I need to create another folder in polls/templates for Django just not to confuse polls index.html with another app's index.html. My assumption was that as long as I'm creating an isolated application, it's templates are also isolated from other apps without any subfolder magic.

Comment: The reason it's done like this is so that apps lower down in the INSTALLED_APPS setting can override previous templates.  For example, you can create a template in admin/poll/poll_changelist.html to override the admin interface for your model.  Anyway, I've updated my answer to include the possibility of using url namespaces.